# JavaScript/jQuery determine the length of a text "in advance"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a web app with jQuery. I have a table with fixed-width columns, and javascript populated row contents.

**Problem:** One column has a width of 140px. Most of the sentences in this column are short and fit into this width. The font is NOT monospaced. There are a few long sentences, and there the td's have 2 lines and the height of
the row becomes greater than 20px.

I do not want this to happen, so I have to shorten the long sentences

**My first idea** was to fill the td with the value and shortly after that to check the height of the td or row. And when the height is larger then 20px I have to shorten the sentence.

But I think this would cause the table rows to "flicker" when the rows get the values.

So **the other idea** is to make a invisible div or span and to do the same thing described as before.

Is there somebody who did this before and found a good solution for my problem?

Comment: Do you have anyway to check the character length of the sentence before you populate the table?

Comment: No. Just in order to implement this feature I have to check it.

Comment: What you can do is to fill the `<td>` with the text but first put the text in a `<div>` with `display:none`, then put that div into the td, and then use `getComputedStyle` to find width/height.

Comment: What about setting the height of the cell and then using overflow: ellipsis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to calculate what the size of the text will be - or at least there's no portable way. You won't even be able to know for sure which font will be used.

What you might do instead is use CSS to force the `td` to a fixed size and ignore all overflowing text. `overflow: hidden` should get you going. Might also want to use `white-space: nowrap` as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could just prevent the resizing with CSS:

```
table { table-layout:fixed; }
table td, table th { white-space:nowrap; overflow:none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about setting the height of the cell and then using text-overflow: ellipsis?

```
table td { text-overflow: ellipsis; max-height: 20px; }
```

**EDIT**: fixed the fiddle - Here's an example:
[JSFiddle - td and ellipsis](http://jsfiddle.net/2pUeh/3/)